# jQuery XOR selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, xor

From a set of divs I want to select all the divs that contain a specific attribute and then select all the divs that do not contain any of the attributes.

Example:

```
<div data-attr="1"></div>
<div data-attr="2"></div>
<div data-attr="3"></div>
<div data-attr="4"></div>
<div data-attr="5"></div>
```

```
var attrList = [3,4];

// I want to process every div containing attr 3 and 4
attrList.forEach(function(item){
    var div = $("[data-attr='"+item+"']");
    div.operation_here()
});

// but I also want to process the remaining divs that do not contain neither attr 3 and 4
/* HELP ME HERE - this would select divs with attr 1, 2 and 5 */
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: An XOR operation would select divs with either data-attr=3 or data-attr=4, but not both (if multiples are possible). Do you have a list of possible data-attr values that aren't 3 or 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it steps by steps. First, select all div:

```
var $div = $('div[data-attr]');
```

---

Then, select those you need:

```
var $valid_div = $div.filter(function(){
     return attrList.indexOf($(this).data('attr')) > -1;
});
```

Now you can do your operation on matching div with your variable:

```
$valid_div.operation_here();
```

---

To select remaining div, you can use `.not()`:

```
var $invalid_div = $div.not($valid_div);
$invalid_div.operation_here();
```

Comment: Exactly this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var $divs = $('div').filter(function() {
  // returns all divs with data-attr not equal 1 or 2 or 5
  return [1, 2, 5].indexOf(this.data('attr')) == -1;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-attr="2">not matched</div>
<div data-attr="5">not matched</div>
<div data-attr="6">matched</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of elements, you can use [`jQuery.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude those elements from another selector

```js
$(function(){
  
    // I want to process every div containing attr 3 and 4
   var divs = $('div[data-attr="3"], div[data-attr="4"]');      
   console.log(divs);  // logs 2
  
   var notDivs = $('div[data-attr]').not(divs);
   console.log(notDivs); // logs the other 3
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-attr="1"></div>
<div data-attr="2"></div>
<div data-attr="3"></div>
<div data-attr="4"></div>
<div data-attr="5"></div>
```